# How can I save my cuddlefish from becoming fish food?

Tags: subnautica

I've just gotten myself a [cuddlefish](http://subnautica.wikia.com/wiki/Cuddlefish), but it keeps getting chomped by hostile creatures around my base. I read that it has a large amount of hp, 10000 in fact, but am unaware of any healing or regeneration options.

Is it possible to heal one's cuddlefish? 
Does it regenerate health over time by itself? 
If it is reduced to 0 hp, is there anything you can do to save it, or do you just have to get a new cuddlefish?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The large health pool thing seems to be incorrect/a myth. They do die quickly to larger predators. Since they follow you everywhere, they tend to find themselves in dire situations quite often. You cannot heal your cuddlefish and the only way to protect it is to leave it in the tank.

And no, they cannot reproduce and there are only 5 cuddlefish eggs in the game.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is build a "tank" for your cuddlefish to be safe while living in the sea.

Essentially this would be a large base with elements built close enough together such that it forms a cage around your cuddlefish.

See image for example (note that your base wouldn't have to be this large to fully encompass your cuddlefish.)

[image: I got bored and built a fortress for my son via Reddit, https://www.reddit.com/r/subnautica/comments/g7cem0/no_spoilers_got_bored_and_made_a_fortress_for_my/]

Answer (score 0):

There's only five in the entire game and for me they all died due to constant stalkers coming from kelp forest to chop them or reaper attacks. Over time they will die so if you can't bear to not have one because of this, just do Debug Cuddle fish and spawn yourself a new one every time it dies due to the hard grind of Subnautica.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell it to 'stay' and it will do just that, swimming around a small area around where you gave the command.  Do this in a safe place and it will be there when you return.